# how to get click event of li element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

can you please tell me how to get click event of `li` .I making `li` element dynamically using `jstree` .
I am press `add` button it create a `li` element internally in `jstree` .can we get click event of that ?
Press `add` two time.it generate `li` element.I want to get click event of `li` .get alert of its id.?
http://jsfiddle.net/GS4u3/4/

```
$('#uu').click(function () {
var ref = $('#tree').jstree(true),
    sel = ref.get_selected();

if (!sel.length) {
    alert('thank')
    sel = ref.create_node("#", {"id" : node_count+1, "text" : node_count+1});
    node_count++;
} else
{
    sel = sel[0];
    sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"id" : node_count+1, "text" : node_count+1}); 
    node_count++;
}
/*if (sel) {
    ref.edit(sel);
}*/
ref.deselect_all();
```

});

Comment: Again: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the job. Since the `li` is created dynamically, you need to [delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which has been superseded by [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$("#tree").on("click", "li > a", function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id");
    $(this).siblings(".jstree-icon").click();
    alert(id);
});
```

EDIT: Making only the text clickable and not the arrow.

EDIT2: http://jsfiddle.net/GS4u3/8/ (edit 4, new jsfiddle with your change updated)

EDIT3: Edited code, to expand the tree upon clicking the text.

Comment: it is not working in my fiddle I already apply can you use fiddle

Comment: @A.Wolff there is problem .it is also clickable of  ">>" this image

Comment: it should be clickable only  text

Comment: @A.Wolff can we get id only click of text .. not on icon..?

Comment: @A.Wolff second we expand li element when user click on "text", open submenu if it is having

Comment: @NaveenSharma I've edited the code to do what you want. It'll only alert if you click on the text and not the arrow. Also here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GS4u3/7/

Comment: @xFortyFourx thanks such great answer .can we expand the if there is any child present on text click ? as now it is expanding on image click ">>"

Comment: @NaveenSharma Yes, I've again edited the code to do what you just said.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51971/discussion-between-naveen-sharma-and-xfortyfourx)